# Why doesn't a +Add App button appear at the top of my Facebook developers pag?

Tags: facebook

I am logged in as myself and not as a company. I previously signed up as a developer and verified with my cell phone number. Can't see +ADD APP button at main www.facebook.com/developers page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to either be the effect of a change, or a legitimate bug. To work around things, try this:

1. Visit https://developers.facebook.com/apps. If you see the "Register
   Now" link, click it to go through the Facebook Developer
   registration process.
2. If the "Create New App" still doesn't show up after registering as a
   Facebook Developer, visit https://developers.facebook.com/setup to
   create a new app.
3. Occasionally, using the setup link to create
   the app will not display the app after filling out the information
   that the popup requests. If this is the case, you can view and edit
   your Facebook App settings by visiting the /apps page.

Comment: Thanks Ben I'll give it a try.  Cheers  -mitch